# ¿Es posible realizar ediciones menores de tipo ortográfico o gramatical a las publicaciones?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

Algunas veces veo preguntas que si bien son de interés general con un pequeño retoque podrían expresar mejor la idea del autor, entre tanto algunas correcciones a las que me refiero simplemente aplican a usar un signo de interrogación de apertura por ejemplo, aunque no es un inconveniente para el lector interpretar lo que autor plantea. ***¿No sería mucho mejor reafirmar nuestra lengua con la acentuación y demás correspondientes?***

Ahora incluso, algunas veces me limito de corregir mis propias publicaciones a fin de evitar sanciones, ya que entiendo que las ediciones permiten tener ganancias en la plataforma y no deseo que se malinterprete la intención ***¿Sería posible renunciar a estas calificaciones en pro de mejorar la calidad de estas publicaciones?***

Comment: Por cierto Neder, te puede ser útil leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Es buena práctica _aceptar_ la respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el tema, tanto en Meta como en el sitio principal.

Answer (score 7):

Entre más se mejore la publicación con la edición, es más probable que sea aceptada por otros miembros de la comunidad.

Por ejemplo

```
Titulo corregido + 
Corrección de etiquetas + 
Formato de código + 
Ortografía y Gramática + 
Remover cosas innecesarias 
= 95% De ser aceptadas
```

Mientras

```
Ortografía y Gramática = 50%
```

Ya que algunos lo consideran como caza de reputación, cuando un usuario tiene pocos puntos.

---

Respondiendo a la pregunta:

> ¿Es posible realizar ediciones menores de tipo ortográfico o
>   gramatical a las publicaciones?

**Si**, pero recuerda que varios usuarios de mucha reputación y que habitualmente votan para aprobar o rechazar tu edición les gusta que las **ediciones sean sustanciales**, y si en algún momento te rechazan una edición no lo tomes a mal. Ve que mas puedes hacer en la siguiente edición para que sea mejor.

PD: También hay usuarios que votan por aprobar la edición aunque sea por errores ortográficos como yo :) aunque sea en un par de palabras. Yo respeto la postura de los demás, recuerda que stackoverflow es una democracia ;)

---

Extra:

Cuando un usuario alcanza [2000 de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) la edición será inmediata y en este caso se considera que eres un usuario con mucha experiencia, por lo que la edición aunque sea pequeña ayudara a la publicación.

Comment: Muy bien explicado. Es interesante destacar el tema del privilegio [Editar Preguntas Y Respuestas](/help/privileges/edit) y que a veces es bueno esperar a tenerlo para hacer modificaciones pequeñas. Al fin y al cabo, hacer una sugerencia de edición te implica a ti y a, al menos, dos revisores, por lo que involucrar a tanta gente por una tilde puede ser una pérdida de tiempo. Por contra, es algo totalmente normal cuando puedes hacerlo tú mismo sin revisión de otros.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo tengo ahora mas claro, esperare a tener una reputación mayor.